# How to find size of a partition in Cassandra using ScalarDB

Tags: scalardb

I am using Scalar DB library which adds ACID support in Cassandra. How can I get the size of the partition using Scalar DB?

In Cassandra Java driver, I would call something like the following to get the size.

```
val resultSet = session.execute(partitionSizeQuery)
      val resultSetSize = resultSet.all.size
```

What is the equivalent for ScalarDB.

I get `Optional[Result]` when I call

```
val result = transaction.get(getQuestion)
```

then I call `.get` to get the value of result if there is a value (after checking `result.isPresent`

```
val resultGet = result.get
    logger.trace(s"result is ${resultGet}")
```

I suppose the above will give me only one row.

I thought of using `Scan` as well as it give `List[Result]` but it is not clear from the documentation whether I'll get all the results or some system/configurable limit.

How do I get size of partition even if i won't get all the wors in one go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `scan` and get the `List<Result>`.
It retrieves all the results from the database, but if the size of a partition is big, it is not recommended to do it.

You can limit the scan range by using `withStart` and `withEnd` API of `Scan`.
https://scalar-labs.github.io/scalardb/javadoc/com/scalar/db/api/Scan.html

It could depend on the underlining implementations if it retrieves only the specified range, but it retrieves only the specified range in Cassandra case.